# access phpmyadmin on localhost & reconfigure phpmyadmin: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've already read many threads on this issue but none of the answers worked for me. I try to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin but it gives me *403 Forbidden* (You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.). So I try to reconfigure phpmyadmin step by step:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

1. **reinstall database for phpmyadmin?**

   > yes
2. **Connection method for MySQL database of phpmyadmin:**

   > Unix socket
3. **MySQL database name for phpmyadmin:**

   > shopware_db
4. **MySQL username for phpmyadmin:**

   > phpmyadmin
5. **MySQL application password for phpmyadmin:**

   > [password chosen]
6. **Password confirmation:**

   > [same password]
7. **Name of the database's administrative user:**

   > root
8. **Web server to reconfigure automatically:**

`[*] apache2
 [ ] lighttpd`

9. (only sometimes after choosing "retry" in the end) **A new version (/tmp/dbconfig-package-config.vagoAL) of configuration file /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.**

   > keep the local version currently installed

#### 10. `An error occurred while installing the database:                                 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

which is something I don't understand, because I can connect to mysql:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
Server version: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)
...
mysql> use shopware_db
Database changed
mysql>
```

Note:
The line `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` is included in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

And here is my **/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf** (I've modified the first lines because that was suggested in one of these answers):

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_php.c>
        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        </IfModule>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen On
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
            AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
        </IfModule>
        Require valid-user
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

#### Edit:

When leaving `Name of the database's administrative user` (Step 7) at default (*debian-sys-maint*) no error occurs. But what user name is that? Where does it come from? Can't I change it to root?

And http://localhost/phpmyadmin is still not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when apache is not configured correctly. All I had to do was to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. Right after

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

add:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also, as mentioned before, you have to set this line at the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```